# How change highlightShape size in the InkResponse widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a bottom navigation bar like the Twitter app has, but I can't find how to customize the highlightShape size.

I can customize corners, colors but not size, I would like to make same size which exceed the bounds of the widget like splash in my builder.

[image: My BottomNavigationBar]

Here is how look my bottom navigation button. Thank you! for help in advance.

```
Center(
  child: Ink(
    height: height,
    width: width,
    child: InkResponse(
      splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
      radius: radiusSize,
      onTap: () {
        const int itemIndex = 1;
        _onTapped(itemIndex);
      },
      child: _pageIndex == 1
        ? Icon(OMIcons.favoriteBorder, color: Colors.black, size: 28.0)
        : Icon(OMIcons.favoriteBorder, color: Colors.grey[600]),
   ),
 ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be an old question but, the "max" radius should match the normal radius if no radius property is specified.

To change the normal radius you should create a custom splashfactory , https://stackoverflow.com/a/51116178/10205629 .

Or as a little hack you could copy the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3bf91b543678d6dc677a9c3f1f2ea32a769ddbcb/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart#L184) and create your own inkresponse modifying the values