# How to Speed up time of splashColor of InkWell in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to increase the time of splashcolor filling activity of InkWell?
Default time is too slow for my work.

Here is my code

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
              child: Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          height: 120,
                          width: 800,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(5),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 120,
                            width: 800,
                            color: Colors.teal,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.red,
                          onTap: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),            
            )
```

And here is the illustration [image]

Comment: I believe this will solve your question, it's the opposite of what you want, but can set the duration to be faster instead of slower https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115401/changing-speed-of-inkwell

Comment: Thanks, It will be helpful to solve the issue :)

Comment: You're most welcome, please update on if this was helpful afterwards.

Comment: will do for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use splashFactory property in InkWell
InkRipple.splashFactory, which defines a splash that spreads out more
aggressively than the default.

`InkWell( splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory, onTap: (){}, child:XWidget, ),`